# How to change the entered text as hyperlink in the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to display the text as hyperlink if the user entered in the text box...

For example if the user entered the text as

"my website name is google.com"...and submit it,

i have to show that text as "my website name is [google.com](http://google.com)"

Is there any plugin available for this or any simple script is enough?

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: The contents of an input (its value) won't be rendered as HTML within it.

Comment: @Bernhard this may work, but it wouldn't work very well for poorly formed URLs as in the OPs example. If you start each URL with `http:` `ftp:` or `https:` then you could regex it easily.

Comment: does website name will be always the last part of string

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thats true or a lot of stuff to match any url but it's possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 2):

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Thanks to:
[How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called "linkify" which I guess is a bit difficult to Google for if you don't know that.

[Here is a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/HitSend/jQuery-linkify) that will do this for you.